# How to retrieve data of specific column and set it to edit text in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

I am new to database . I have two tables in database one is user

```
"Create Table user(username text , contact_number text primary key , password text , favourite_fruit text"
```

and keywords

```
"Create Table keywords( contact_number text primary key  , alarm text  , location text )"
```

I want to retrieve data of column alarm from keywords and set it to Edit text in activity but I am unable to retrieve data of alarm column.
So far I have tried this :

```
public String getAlarm(String al){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 

        Cursor cursor=db.query("keywords",new String[]{"alarm"},"contact_number=?",new String[]{al},null,null,null,null);
        String a;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("alarm"));
        } else {
            a = " ";
        }
        return a;
}
```

and this:

```
 public String getAlarm(String al){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // to get database in readable format

     // Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select alarm from keywords where contact_number=? ",new String[]{al});
 String a;  //storing the required value
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                a = cursor.getString(0);// each item will be stored
                return a;   // returning the required value
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

and this:

```
 public String getAlarm(String al){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // to get database in readable format

      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select alarm from keywords where contact_number=? ",new String[]{al});
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            cursor.getString(1); // will fetch you the data
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        return " ";
}
```

My database file is executing every query of user table but for keywords table it just execute its insertkeys function and no other query regarding keywords table.I dont understand whether the problem is with my query or with my table.So I am posting my database file too

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // constructor
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Offline Mobile Finder.db", null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("Create Table user(username text , contact_number text primary key , password text , favourite_fruit text)");
        db.execSQL("Create Table keywords( contact_number text primary key  , alarm text  , location text )");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists user");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists keywords");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //  data of user table
    public boolean insert (String username,String contact_no ,String password ,String fav_fruit ){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //ContentValues is a name value pair, used to insert or update values into database tables.
        // ContentValues object will be passed to SQLiteDataBase objects insert() and update() functions.
      //  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username",username);
        contentValues.put("contact_number",contact_no);
        contentValues.put("password",password);
        contentValues.put("favourite_fruit",fav_fruit);
        long ins = db.insert("user",null,contentValues);
        //  db.close();
        if(ins == -1)
            return  false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    // values insert in keywords table
    public boolean insertkeys (String alarm ,String location ,String contact){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //ContentValues is a name value pair, used to insert or update values into database tables.
        // ContentValues object will be passed to SQLiteDataBase objects insert() and update() functions.
        //  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("alarm",alarm);
        contentValues.put("location",location);
        contentValues.put("contact_number",contact);
        long ins = db.insert("keywords",null,contentValues);
        long upd = db.update("keywords",contentValues,"contact_number = ?",new String[]{contact});
        //  db.close();
        if(ins == -1 && upd == -1)
            return  false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public String getAlarm(String al) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // to get database in readable format

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select alarm from keywords where contact_number=? ", new String[]{al});
        String result = "";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return result;



    }

    // checking if contact number exists in register activity
    public boolean checkContactNo (String contact_no){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        //Cursors are what contain the result set of a query made against a database in Android.
        // The Cursor class has an API that allows an app to read (in a type-safe manner) the columns
        // that were returned from the query as well as iterate over the rows of the result set.

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from user where contact_number=?", new String[] {contact_no} );
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0 )
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
  public String getUsernameThroughContactNo(String contactNo){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // to get database in readable format
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select username from user where contact_number=?",new String[]{contactNo});
        String a;   //storing the required value
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                a = cursor.getString(0);// each item will be stored
                return a;   // returning the required value
               }
         while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

I am trying to show the value of getAlarm() in other activity in toast but on the execution of every query I have tried it shows nothing in toast.Even if I try to get contact_number from this table it crashes.
Searched so much to solve the problem but didn't get solution.I hope here someone will find problem and give solution.Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 1st try, with this:

```
a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("balance"));
```

you try to get the value of the column `"balance"` instead of `"alarm"`.
 
Your 2nd try looks ok, although you don't need the `do` loop since you `return` after you get the first value.
 
In your 3d try the error is:

```
cursor.getString(1);
```

The index `1` is wrong, it should be `0` because the column indexes are 0 based. 
But the problem is also that you do not save the value anywhere and finally you return `" "`!!! Why?
You should do something like:

```
public String getAlarm(String al){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select alarm from keywords where contact_number=? ",new String[]{al});
    String result = "";
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but all these changes you have told me shows nothing.I also tried to run your query to get contact_number but after it gives me contact_number my app crashes. Is it because both of my tables have same column name (contact_number) plus contact_number field is primary key also in both tables. I am new to database So have no idea what is going on here.Thanks for your help again in advance :)

Comment: In all 3 tries of your original question only the table `keywords` is involved in the queries. So there is no case of conflicting column names. If you get nothing by the code is there a case that the table has no data or the number you are searching does not exist? You say that when you run my query *after it gives me contact_number my app crashes* so do you get the contact_number? If you do then the code is correct and the app crashes due to something else that is executed afterwards.

Comment: @AzmatInayat if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark at the left.

Comment: Yes... You are right its working pretty good Thanks a lot . As you said   _If you get nothing by the code is there a case that the table has no data or the number you are searching does not exist?_ But my database is showing all the values I have inserted in keywords. I have posted my db file above.Can you take a look at that and tell me that my values are inserting correctly or not.

Comment: Your insert() method seems correct, but you can check it if it return true. If it does then it's ok. But what are you doing in insertkeys()? Why insert and update?

Comment: insert() is for user table but for keywords table I have used insertkeys() to insert keywords(alarm,location,contact_number).I need to insert keywords into the table plus every time if user comes again to change the values of keys on the same button click then it should then update them.That is why I did both at the same time

Comment: Every time insertkeys() is executed a new row is inserted to the table and immediately updated so if you think that this method can do insert or update then you are wrong. It does both at the same time. I think you need 2 separate methods.

Comment: I have tried that also separate update method I made and in activity I call it like if(insertkeys() || update()) then insert values.But even then it just pick contact_number from table when I run query .Alarm and Location I am unable to get.Don't know why.